# Non-Persistent Linux from HDD

Tags: linux, embedded, persistence

I am developing a embedded product that will be running linux on hardware similar to a raspberry pi but with internal storage.  I would like it so that the power can be cut to the machine and have a very low risk of corruption.  I was considering that a live version of linux would not do HDD writes so it could never be mid write.

In all the use cases I have seen, this is normally done on a USB drive.  I want to install this to the internal storage so it can boot from it.

Also in a perfect world, it would be easy to update the image directly, for example, creating a file and then "updating" the image on disk to include that file.

Does a version of linux support something like this?  Also how would the install work to get the non-persistent install installed on an internal drive and not a flash drive?

Comment: A ramdisk or otherwise read-only filesystem is your answer - if you need configuration, then store it on a separate read/write partition.

Comment: It sounds like the project has a few unanswered questions - e.g: what is your storage? (raw flash / eMMC / spinning hard disk). There are different steps you'll need to take for each of these to help with reliability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am developing a embedded product ...

Devices that run embedded Linux typically have a custom kernel and custom root filesystem.  Typically it's not worth the effort to try to tailor an existing Linux distribution to custom hardware and use a general-purpose desktop filesystem for a dedicated embedded application.
Tools for building custom Linux kernel and root filesystems are Buildroot and Yocto.

> Does a version of linux support something like this?

A *"live version of linux"* is simply a Linux kernel that boots with a ramdisk or more likely a ramfs for the root filesystem.  I've seen (as well as built) numerous embedded Linux system that use a ramfs or ramdisk for its rootfs.
IOW what you propose is neither unique or new; it's a well-used concept that has many implementation variations.

The boot media is up to you and what the hardware supports.
IOW if you want to boot Linux with an initramfs from a HDD, then the only problem could be you learning how to build it.
Depending on what hardware you use, there could be no new code to develop (aside from your application), and building such a kernel and rootfs would be a matter of downloading, configuring and building existing source code.

Updating a system out in the field is a complex topic, and there are many solutions.  The various package systems as used by distros is typically too heavy/complex for embedded systems, especially those that are NAND flash-based.

Answer (score 2):

FIrst off, you actually can boot a 'live' system like this from a hard drive or other persistent storage pretty easily.  Just write out the image you would put on the USB flash drive to whatever storage, and boot from that.  Many kiosk type systems do this, as do a lot of thin-clients.

Now, that said, this is probably not the best option for your use case.  I would very much suggest taking a look at how Android and ChromeOS handle their root filesystems.  Both are designed to be extremely resilient against corruption caused by unexpected power loss, and both also provide tamper protection by default (IOW, you'll know if someone modified the data while the device was off).  Similar setups can be achieved without too much difficulty with a custom root filesystem made by [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/).

As an alternative to that, you might consider looking at [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/).  It's designed to be run from read-only media, though I'm not sure how well it supports things other than 64-bit x86 systems.